# How to use v-model on a slot in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-model, slots

I am trying to find a way to use a model component I made but with the ability to close the model from one of the slots.

I can pass data to the slot but not with v-model and dont believe I can change the slot prop to close the model open state

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots

this is my popover in use

```
<PopoverModal>
    <template #toggleButton>
      <button>A</button>
    </template>
    <template #modalContent="{ toggleModal }">
      <div style="color: #fff; height: 400px; width: 400px;">test2 {{toggleModal}}</div>
      <button @click="toggleModal = false">click me</button>
    </template>
  </PopoverModal>
```

within the popover component I am trying to be able to send the state var

```
<slot name="modalContent" :toggleModal="showSelector"></slot>
```

I'm guessing the answer is its not possible and to find another way but if anyone knows that would be great thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change PopoverModal data directly using template, but you can bind some setter methods.

Some example code:

HelloWorld.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <PopoverModal>
      <template #toggleButton>
        <button>A</button>
      </template>
      <template #modalContent="modelContent">
        <div style="color: #fff; height: 400px; width: 400px;">test2 {{modelContent.toggleModal}}</div>
        <button @click="modelContent.setToggleModal(false)">click me</button>
      </template>
    </PopoverModal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PopoverModal from './PopoverModal'
export default {
  components: {PopoverModal},
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

PopoverModal.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="toggleButton"></slot>
    <slot name="modalContent" :toggleModal="showSelector" :setToggleModal="setShowSelector"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      showSelector: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setShowSelector(showSelector) {
      this.showSelector = showSelector;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. You just need to remember what a v-model is; for example:

```
<SomeComponent v-model="someProp"/>
```

Is the exactly same thing as:

```
<SomeComponent :value="someProp" @input="setSomeProp" />
```

***Observation:*** Just remember that function `setSomeProp` of the example receives the value as function `param`.

So, to a v-model at v-slot, we can bind the prop and a listener of an `input` event and we will have a v-model; for example:

```
<template>
    <slot
        name="foo"
        :bind="{ value: someProp }"
        :on="{ input: setSomeProp }"
    />
</template>
<script>

export default {

    data() {
        someProp: ''
    },

    methods: {
        setSomeProp(value) {
            this.someProp = value
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And, at the component `usign`, the component with slot:

```
<template>

    <ComponentWithSlot>

        <template #foo="{ bind, on }">
            <SomeComponent v-on="on" v-bind="bind" />
        </template>

    </ComponentWithSlot>

</template>
```

***Observation:*** It's a example of how lib does this (i.e., how the Vuetify with `v-menu` and `v-tooltip`), but has N ways to do this; you just need to remember to bind the prop and a setter function to the input event—and, if you use a `v-model`, not with `input` but with event of 'change', you will need a listener of `change`, so the recommendation may be this:

```
<template>
    <slot
        name="foo"
        :bind="{ value: someProp }"
        :on="{
            input: setSomeProp,
            change: setSomeProp
        }"
    />
</template>
<script>

export default {

    data() {
        someProp: ''
    },

    methods: {
        setSomeProp(value) {
            this.someProp = value
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

***General Observation:*** `value` and `input` are respectively prop value and event 'defaults', with Vue 3 and multiple v-models—if I'm not mistaken—we will have:

```
<SomeComponent v-model="someProp" v-model:peer="peer" />
```

Is the same that:

```
 <SomeComponent
     :value="someProp"
     @input="setSomeProp"
     :peer="peer"
     @input:peer="setPeer"
 />
```

Remembering that event of the example can be `change:peer` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an object and use its properties with v-model it works, but I think that it is not recommended (at least in Vue 2.x).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CDN en Vue 3</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <child>
        <template v-slot:default="props">
          <h3>Slot</h3>

          <p>
            Object.val: <input v-model="props.data.val"> : {{props.data.val}} (binding works)
          </p>
        </template>
      </child>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const child = {
  template: `
    <h3>Component</h3>

    <p>
      Object.val: <input v-model="data.val"> : {{data.val}} (binding works)
    </p>

    <hr>

    <slot :data="data" :val="val"></slot>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      data: {val: 1},
      val: 'asd'
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rjurado/un3sdqte/30/